# Пройти по каждому элементу массива и сверить с шаблоном?

Tags: php

Есть массив в котором лежат ссылки вида http://site.ru/question/new/ и похожие на эту. Как мне пройти по каждому элементу массива и сверить с шаблоном? Если Url в массиве начинается на http://site.ru/2015/ записываем всю ссылку в отдельную переменную. Помогите решить задачу.

Comment: [RTFM](http://www.php.su/functions/?cat=array), решений задачи больше одного.

Comment: @eprivalov1, схема, хост (`http://site.ru`) не меняются?

Comment: @romeo не меняется

Answer (score 1):

```
$urls = [
    'http://site.ru/question/new/',
    'http://site.ru/2015/'
];


$result = [];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    if (preg_match('#http://site\.ru/\d+/#i', $url)) {
        $result['year'] = $url;
        continue;
    }

    if (preg_match('#http://site\.ru/question/.*#i', $url)) {
            $result['question'] = $url;
            continue;
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

[**Смотрите результат**](http://3v4l.org/llZ39)

Regxp-правила/паттерны можно как-то систематизировать, чтобы не повторять каждый раз оператор `if`.

Comment: А какой смысл вручную писать функционал `array_filter()`?

Comment: @klopp ТС необходимо раскидать входящий массив с урл-ами по переменными. Тогда уместно `array_map()`.

Comment: Честно говоря, не очень понятно, по какому принципу нужно раскидывать и что значит "отдельная переменная". Если просто где-то сохранить определённые ссылки, то и `array_filter()` сгодится, привязка к каким-то ключам нигде не оговорена.

Comment: Всё верно. Мало информации. Так или иначе, из двух предложенных ответов можно собрать решение.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и быстрый способ сделать это - обойти все элементы массива и поискать вхождение нужной подстроки (см. Php strpos())

```
   foreach ($links_array as $link) {
      if (strpos($link, 'http://site.com/2015/') === 0) {
        // сохраняем ссылку $link в переменную
      }
    }
```

Для реализации более сложной логики можно использовать регулярные выражения (preg_match).